# Slim proxy redirection to VueJS localhost server

Tags: php, apache, vue.js, slim

I'm using the PHP [SLIM](http://www.slimframework.com/) framework, and I would like to serve for development purposes a `vuejs dev` server on localhost (server side).

I want to do something like this :

```
$app->get('/dev/vuejs', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    return $response->withRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
});
```

This does not work as I would like and actually just tell the client to look for that URI.

What I want :
[image]

What I got :
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe what you want and let us know what's wrong with code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand but I guess you trying to render / compile `*.vue` files via Slim on a `vuejs/vue-dev-server`.

Here is a proof of concept using curl:

```php
$app->get('/dev/vuejs', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Change the url here
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $responseBody = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($responseBody === false) {
        $response->getBody()->write('HTTP error: ' . curl_error($ch));

        return $response->withStatus(500);
    }

    $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $responseBody = trim(substr($responseBody, $headerSize));
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    $response->getBody()->write($responseBody);

    return $response->withStatus($httpCode);
});
```